# With C++, use QWebView to display HTML text, rather than a web page somewhere on the web

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to programmaticaly create a (long) string of HTML text and then load it in a `QWebView` widget?

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
void WebBrowser::SetText(string sText)
{
   ui->webView->setText(QString::fromUtf8(sText.c_str()));
}
```

but then of course the code above doesn't work because webView doesn't have a setText member function.

(I'm aware I could simply display HTML text in a label but I'd like to have some of functionality of `QWebView` to do things such as hypertext links to pages on the web, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called [setHtml()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebview.html#setHtml).

That said, at this point you should be considering switching to [WebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html), since Qt WebKit is a deprecated module.  WebEngine also has a [setHtml()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#setHtml) method.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the advice re WebEngine.